# Can a Child node have multiple Parent nodes in Collapsible Force Layout using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a visualization similar to http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130, with huge amount of data. I could not figure out if it is possible that a child node can have multiple parent nodes? for instance, as per the visualization shown in the previously mentioned link, can **"shortestPaths"** have parents **"graph"** as well as **"optimization"**? I have looked around stackoverflow. Could not find answer that solves this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible, if you rely on the example you linked to at the beginning of the question. This is because of this code:

```
  var nodes = flatten(root),
  links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
```

`d3.layout.tree()` requires tree-like data (no multiple parents).

Of course, you can always develop entirely yours solution that will handle such cases. But you can't do it based on the example you mentioned.